# Emacs Evil-mode search and replace - Wrong number of arguments

Tags: emacs, emacs24, evil-mode

I am running into an error when I try to run a search and replace in Emacs using Evil-mode. The search I'm using is `:s/14/12/g`. I've tried without the `g` and get the same error. This is exactly the same search I'd do in Vim. The error returned indicates I have the wrong number of arguments.

```
byte-code: Wrong number of arguments: #[(string) "Æ{{A WHOLE BUNCH OF \211's and 
such HERE}}" [flags replacement pattern string evil-ex-substitute-replacement args
nil string-match "^[a-zA-Z]" "[^[:space:]]+" ...] 6
("c:/Users/Ryan/Documents/GitHub/Vim/.emacs.d/elpa/evil-1.0.7/evil-search.elc" . 
33836)], 2
```

Am I just searching wrong with Evil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact error after running a package upgrade, which included evil.

I believe the root cause however was that I had an old reference to a manually installed evil folder in my init.el loadpath.

I removed that, quit & restarted emacs, and the problem had resolved itself. If you don't have the same init.el problem, perhaps just try removing and reinstalling evil.

Comment: Not sure if it was fixed in the evil package, but everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this error today as well.  It seems like there is something wrong with the compiled lisp files (.elc).  Try to recompile your evil directory with `(byte-recompile-directory "c:/Users/Ryan/Documents/GitHub/Vim/.emacs.d/elpa/evil-1.0.7" 0 t)`.  Or, if you like, simply delete all *.elc files.

Comment: Hmm. Tried the recompile, but to no avail. Everything was recompiled, but the error still shows up.